# How to find elements that sum up to ten in array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to print elements in the array that add up to ten, but I get this error:

```
 8 : 25 : 55 : 5TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

This is my code:

```
array =  [6, 2, 7, 1, 10, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 10, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5, 5]
def print(array)
  array.each_with_index.inject(0) do |m,(roll,i)|
    if array[i] + array[i+1] == 10 
      print "#{array[i]} : #{array[i+1]}"
    end
  end
end
```

My desired output is:

```
8:2,5:5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: first step to fix it is to ask a question that at least one person will understand...

Comment: I changed two to ten. Is that better, @AndreyDeineko ?

Comment: think about what will happen when `i` is the index of the last element of `array`

Comment: Right, ruby is expecting another number after the last number in the array, hence the nil error.

Comment: Why are you using `inject` while completely ignoring `m`?

Comment: The method's original purpose was to add up the values that equaled two. I changed the method for debugging purposes.

Comment: Wait so your goal is to print a list of every unique pair of elements in the array which sum up to 10, ie 8+2, 7+3, 10+0 etc?

Comment: Consider whether you want the zero. For each collection not including a zero that sums to 10, there is another collection which equals the original collection with a zero added. For example, `[2,8]` and [2,8,0]` both sum to `10`. If you have, say, three zeroes, `[2,8,0,0]` and `[2,8,0,0,0] also sume to `10`.

Comment: Can you post the required output for the array given in your example?

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match the description of the problem in your question. I would expect the output to be `"0:1:2:2:2:3, 0:1:2:2:5, 0:1:2:7, 0:1:3:6, 0:1:9, 0:2:2:6, 0:2:3:5, 0:2:8, 0:3:7, 0:5:5, 0:10, 1:2:2:2:3, 1:2:2:5, 1:2:7, 1:3:6, 1:9, 2:2:6, 2:3:5, 2:8, 3:7, 5:5, 10"`

Comment: Wow. The method was for debugging purposes. I am doing a bowling kata. The kata reads: If a player knocks down 10 pins with two rolls, then this is a SPARE. The score for this frame is 10 plus the total number of pins knocked down in the next roll.

Comment: I am simply trying to determine if I have a spare at this point. Sorry for the confusion. @JörgWMittag

Comment: Since there are no answers yet you can and should edit your question to state that you want all pairs of numbers from the array that sum to `10`, but the first cannot be `10`.

Comment: I'm gonna sit on it. Feeling a bit frustrated. Thanks Cary.

Comment: Your question is *still* extremely unclear. In the last paragraph, you say that your desired output is `8:2,5:5`. In the comments, you say you want to detect spares, but the `8:2` isn't a spare, only the `5:5` is, so the result should be `5:5`, not `8:2,5:5`. The answer you accepted as correct detects spares **and strikes**, yet in the comments you only mention spares (and in the question, you don't mention bowling at all). In the question, you only talk about an arbitrary number of arbitrary elements that add up to 10, for which the correct result would be the one I posted in my comment above

Comment: You now have 4 different interpretations of your question, you *really* need to clear it up. Relevant information belongs *in the question*, not hidden away in comments.

Comment: @JörgWMittag it is a spare. If a person scores a strike which is a score of ten, then the player does not get a second turn. So the nine after the first ten would count as roll 1.

Comment: Then you should put that *in the question*, where one can see it. You still haven't specified the input format, nor have you clarified what "elements in the array that add up to ten" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#inject` is a weird method to use for this purpose. The way you've written it, a nil is being returned as the aggregator which is why you're not getting the desired result. Remove it and the logic is clearer:

```
array =  [6, 2, 7, 1, 10, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 10, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5, 5]
def print(array)
  pairs = []
  array.each_with_index do |val, idx|
    next if idx == 0
    prev_val = array[idx - 1]
    curr_total = val + prev_val
    if curr_total == 10
      pairs << [prev_val, val]
    end
  end

  pairs.map { |pair| pair.join(':') }.join(',')
end
```

Comment: I have realized the error in my question. I should not have written it while I was tired and hungry. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: If the `9` in `array` is changed to `0`, `print(array) #=> "10:0,8:2,5:5,5:5"`, but the OP made it clear in comments that it the bowling *spares* that are to be idenfied. That is, `"10:0"` should not be printed.

Comment: That was not clear in the question when I submitted my answer. In fact, it's barely clear in the comments. The bowling talk was in a hidden comment. I had to go digging for it. My solution answers the question as stated. If the OP updates the question with bowling-specific requirements, I'll update the answer and also account for the edge-case where `0:10` is included (since a gutter ball followed by a "strike" in the same frame is really a spare).

Answer (score 1):

```
array =  [6, 2, 7, 1, 10, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 10, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5, 5]

array.flat_map { |n| n == 10 ? [10, 0] : n }.
      each_slice(2).
      select { |ball1,ball2| ball1 != 10 && ball1+ball2.to_i == 10 }
  #=> [[8, 2], [5, 5]]
```

The steps are as follows. Firstly, use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) to insert a zero after each `10` (in bowling, a *strike*):

```
a = array.flat_map { |n| n == 10 ? [10, 0] : n }
  #=> [6, 2, 7, 1, 10, 0, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 0, 10, 0, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```

This allows us to use [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to divide `array` into pairs:

```
e = a.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [6, 2, 7, 1, 10, 0, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 0, 10, 0, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5, 5]
  #   :each_slice(2)>
```

We can use [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) (or [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a)) to see the values that will be generated by this enumerator and pass on to `select`:

```
e.entries
  #=> [[6, 2], [7, 1], [10, 0], [9, 0], [8, 2], [10, 0], [10, 0], [3, 5],
  #    [7, 2], [5, 5], [5]]
```

Note the array of size one `[5]` at the end. Continuing,

```
e.select { |ball1,ball2| ball1 != 10 && ball1+ball2.to_i == 10 }
  #=> [[8, 2], [5, 5]]
```

When the last element of `e` (`[5]`) is generated, `select`'s block variables are computed as follows:

```
ball1, ball2 = [5]
  #=> [5] 
ball1
  #=> 5 
ball2
  #=> nil
```

Had the block above contained `&& ball1+ball2 == 10` this would have raised an exception (unless the inclusion of the last element of `array` was a mistake in the formulation of the example). That could have been handled with a `if ball2.nil? ...` statement, but I chose to instead simply convert `ball2` to an integer. If it's already an integer, that value is returned; it it equals `nil`, `nil.to_i #=> 0`. See [NilClass#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i).